# filter on prefetch entity using persistence js

Tags: javascript, orm

I'm new to persistence js and I'm not sure if its possible to apply filter on a prefetch entity. I was using websql as store.

Below is the example that I was trying,

```
var Category = persistence.define("Category", { categoryName : 'TEXT'});
var Expense = persistence.define("Expense", { expenseAmount : 'INT'});
Category.hasMany("expenses",Expense,"category");

//Query to get all expense related to a category - but this didn't work
Expense.all().prefetch("category").filter("categoryName","=","TestCategory");
```

Is there a way to make it work?